# Is there a more versatile Social component than Community Builder?

Tags: templates

A website we are developing is based on the Community Board platform. We are unable to place a slideshow alongside a fixed photo because CB does not allow its placement there and have the website remain responsive. This is a serious constraint because the photo and slideshow alongside one another is critical for the purpose of the website.

Is there a more flexible platform than CB?

Comment: Community Board or Community Builder?

Answer (score 1):

Besides [Community Builder](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/community-builder), you have other extensions, among them [JomSocial](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jomsocial) or [EasySocial](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/easysocial).

All of them provide templating features to extend the basic layout.